# Is there a way to take screenshots of an entire ViewController in Interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I do all my work on a 13" macbook and there are times when I need to send the designer screenshots of the ViewController I'm working on. Usually I have to take multiple screenshots but I was wondering if anyone knows of an app or a way to do it from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to send a screenshot from the simulator? You could run your app, navigate to your ViewController and presse `Cmd + S` to save a screenshot on your desktop. Here it doesn't matter if the simulator is bigger than your screen, the screenshot will always show the whole ViewController.

Comment: That works ok when I need to send a screenshot of the final product. But there are times when I need to send a screenshot of an image that is not fitting correctly, specially when skinning an app. Hopefully, there's something out there?